# Can I add a 2nd trap into existing with T for this cat fountain?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, p-trap

I am adding an automatic cat water fountain. The flow will be minimal, when this turns on by motion sensor.

Can I connect this fountain into the existing plumbing between the trap and the wall with a Y connection?

Can I bring down the bottom of the fountain(sink) to just above the level of the pipe to wall as seen in the following?

[image]
Showing initial idea to connect to sink thru cabinet
[image]
I don't have great access to bath drain without damaging this hard side(fake marble)..
[image]
**Update**: Current plan is to cut access point here so can tie into bathtub drain.  Then put a mosaic tile band around sides to cover.
[image]

**How I plan fountain portion to work**
This is the faucet I purchased, I don't need the valves/handle for it.
[image]

I intend to use a combination of a Normally Closed Valve and a PIR motion sensor.

This is one option for the PIR, but I will have to research placement after fountain is installed.  Ideally, it will be wall mounted and have a 45 degree offset to not be triggered by walking by / being in tub.

[PIR on Amazon](https://a.co/d/4fY5coX)
[image]

This is one option for the normally closed valve,  I will take time to choose the one when get to that part of project.

[NO Valve](https://a.co/d/4fY5coX)
[image]

Considerations are to to tuck these up high in the vanity.  The other vanity has an electrical outlet in/outside of it so its easy to bring sealed conduit over out of sight and mimic placement.

We have dogs with a water bowl our older cat shuns.  She always sits right about where the placement of the fountain is.  If it turns out the PIR doesn't work as hoped, I'll snag a WIFI light switch, the kind the the buttons with 1, 5 min timers.  When I walk by and water is demanded, I can hit the button for it to run for a couple min.

Comment: I suspect you might get some backflow into the fountain.

Comment: So...out of curiosity, how is this cat fountain supposed to work?  I see your photo shows basically a little sink, with what appear to be holes for a faucet and a drain.  How is the faucet supposed to be turned on?

Comment: @Huesmann, edited OP to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks **highly** dubious.

I would suggest a Y pipe ("dishwasher drain inlet") on the tailpiece of the sink above the sink trap, and something like a small condensate pump to take the cat fountain drainage **up** to that level.

Alternatively, elevate the cat fountain by mounting it in a "cat tree" or "cat tower" sort of structure the cats can easily climb  to reach the fountain at a higher level.

Comment: You might say why you think so. The inadequate slope? The dual traps?

Comment: I added a 2nd image for visual reference.  I will consider condensate pump, I will already have an electric valve.  Is only issue to address, backflow?  If so would a PVC In-line Check Valve work?  Else, I will consider elevating.   If I use a T instead of a Y on the tail piece, I can raise this approx 3 inches to keep flush with backsplash in image.

Comment: Your added photograph appears to show the fountain on top of the counter, so given the sink and its trap go below the counter, the drawing does not appear to be correct about the relationship in height, unless you are re-locating the fountain from where it's shown in the photograph? A simple gravity drain would work from there into the sink tailpiece above the sink trap...

Comment: The photo shows the sink on top of the Bath Tub ledge and if you look at the top right of the image, you see the sink(in the cabinet) elevated.  I have measured the run for the drawing and believe its accurate.  - The tub is surrounded with coutner material I can't access well, so want to hook into sink via cabinet.

Comment: ...so connect to the bath drain instead of the sink drain.

Comment: The wall of the bath tub is made of countner top material.  I don't have access, its not sheetrock or tile I could repair.

Comment: I really like the condensate pump idea. It could be housed in a short platform underneath, and a really small drain line could poke through the drywall to the left of the vanity, then into the vanity for a drain connection. Only hard part might be power for the pump.

Comment: What's your objection to raising the fountain a little higher?  If you have a double kitchen sink go see how the drain is plumbed.  One sink has no trap, just drains into the tail of the other.  That's all you need, as suggested in this answer.  Cats are renowned for climbing ... why not let the cat do the work instead of creating something that needs power and maintenance to drive water uphill? If you want a smaller pipe use a hose and dishwasher connection instead of a double-sink connection.  Still don't need a pump!

Comment: Also if you *do* use a condensate pump, perhaps you should put the fountain on the floor so the jaccuzi won't always be full of cat hair!

Comment: Higher means more clutter, less clean look plus 1 cat is turning 16 soon.  We have never used the tub (jets gross us out \  wife wants a new tub).  I want to glue door stops over jets and call it a day.  From every thing I am hearing, I am leaning towards getting access to tub drain and replace the cultured marble piece (when it breaks).  Its $200 at Floor & Decor if I need large piece.  I don't like idea of depending on electricity / pump for drain.

Comment: Tub access is often painful, but here it looks like you might be able to go in via the lavatory cabinet (either cut a hole in the sidewall, or disconnect the sink plumbing and move the whole thing) and miss the cultured marble entirely. The other classic option if it's not on a slab is to get to it from below (up through the ceiling/floor.) When you replace it to make your wife happy, put an access panel on the new one.

Comment: I don't really understand how this thing would get connected to the tub drain.  Tub drains don't usually have tail-pieces, not ones long enough for a second incoming connection, and even if some do I wouldn't want to embed a dishwasher-style connector under the floor.  So we're talking about a second trap in the void below the fountain, with its own drain and vent connections to the riser?  I think that would require breaking open more than just the ceiling below.  Go with the pump and the dishwasher tail in the cabinet, the first thing suggested in this answer.

Comment: @jay613 Stock tub overflow is a nice long hunk of tailpiece-type /size tubing going into a slip joint at the tee where the drain shoe joins, unless you have a glued PVC/ABS job, and if you do, it's a long accessible hunk of PVC/ABS.

Comment: @ecnerwal --- hitting the overflow through the side of the cabinet, if it just happens to be *right there* is the best idea of all .. put it in the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the dialog.  Bathtub drain shoe(?) is too far from vanity to reach.  Added image.  Now considering cutting access into cultured marble to be able to tie into.  I can do a nice tile band around the sides after I place it back.

Comment: I see this tub without jets on Facebook market place every month or so.  Anyone know, since I don't care about keeping jets if I can disconnect drain from top and faucet, cut  caulk like and lift tup up and out without bottom / side access?  This is on slab concrete(on grade).

Comment: @ttugates make that a new question